# excluir registo de uma tabela sql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Boas pessoal eu quero apagar um registo de uma tabela mas para isso preciso de ir buscar informação a outras tabelas e por causa disso não estou a conseguir apagar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu basicamente precisava de um comando SQL que recebesse o id do paciente da tabela pacientes, via quais os `id_agregado` pertencem a esse paciente na tabela `utenteagregado` e apagava tudo pertencente a esse `id_agregado` na tabela `agregado`. Eu já tentei mas todos os comandos dão me erro de sintax.

Obrigado

Comment: sua pergunta está muito ampla, por favor, adicione suas consultas SQL que causam erros, se possível crie a estrutura e os dados em http://sqlfiddle.com/ e adicione o link aqui

Comment: Ja esta resolvido, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha se ajuda

```
DELETE FROM AGREGADO
WHERE AGREDADO.ID_AGREGADO IN (
  SELECT utenteagregado.ID_AGREGADO FROM utenteagregado
  WHERE utenteagregado.ID_PACIENTE = ?
)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, exatamente isso que eu queria